# HDFS replication factor in hdfs-site.xml not reflected when uploading new files onto HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication

I am created a HDFS cluster, with one namenode, two datenodes, and one secondary namenode. So, in total four machines/servers (with four IPs).

The configuration (core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, ...) is set up on the namenode and then copied to the  ~/hadoop.X.X.X/etc/hadoop folder on the two datanodes and the one secondary namenode.

In the hdfs-site.xml ,

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>
```

The replication factor is set as 2.  However, every time when I upload data onto HDFS, on the web interface, the replication factor is always 3, and the corresponding file is under-replicated.

[image]

I can of course run `hadoop fs -setrep -w 2 /hdfsPathToTheFile` to change the replication factor from 3 back to 2.  And when i have run `hadoop fs -setrep -w 2 /` for all the existing files, then no file is reported under-replicated.

However, I want to avoid such situation and want the `dfs.replication` (=2) defined in hdfs-site.xml reflected for the newly uploaded file.

The same problem has been discussed here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Replication-factor-in-HDFS/td-p/117934, but no answer solves my problem.

On stackoverflow, these two posts are also similar: [HDFS replication property not reflecting as defined in hfs-site.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764747/hdfs-replication-property-not-reflecting-as-defined-in-hfs-site-xml) , [HDFS replication factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630787/hdfs-replication-factor)

I have tried to follow their advice, e.g. `hdfs dfsadmin -refreshNodes` , and/or restart hadoop cluster, and/or even re-install a completely new hadoop cluster.  But none seems solves the problem that the `dfs.replication (=2)` is not reflected for the newly uploaded files.

Anyone has idea?

Comment: I do not know what happens, but magic happens when I restart the HDFS (start-dfs.sh) again. Now the dfs.replication on the HDFS web interface is shown as 2.

Comment: you probably configured `hdfs-site.xml` after start it.